# Symfony3 LDAP user authentication

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

Am writing a Symfony3 app and want to config LDAP conection for users to login.

So i need to connect to service directory fetch the user object and check in that object weather the username and password match agains user login page input.

To achieve this am planing to use a combination of these two bundles:

```
FR3DLdapBundle
FOSUserBundle
```

But there something I dont understand i.e: for FOSUserBundle i will create user entity, does this user entity class params need to be exacley as the attributes from the SD object?

also i have a database for the app I only want to use LDAP connection to authenticate users because thats where the username and password is stored.

can you guys help me understand this process thx.

Symfony LDAP componetn error:

So i have followed the SYmfony documentation replicated the code but still got this error message even the code is identical:

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "app.ldap".
in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Reference), object(Reference), 'api', object(Reference), '{username}@example', true)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 42
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 53
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition))) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 51
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition)), true)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 42
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 36
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 545
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 477
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 166
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
at require('app_dev.php') in router_dev.php line 40
```

app/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    app.ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Ldap\Ldap
        arguments: [ "ldap.example.com" ]
```

app/config/security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
#        in_memory:
#            memory: ~
        app_users:
            ldap:
                service: app.ldap
                base_dn: dc=example,dc=com
                search_dn: CN=My User,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
                search_password: p455w0rd
                filter: (sAMAccountName={username})
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
#
    firewalls:
        api:
            provider:  app_users
            stateless: true
            pattern:   ^/api
            http_basic_ldap:
                service: app.ldap
                dn_string: "{username}@example"
        backend:
            provider: app_users
            pattern:  ^/admin
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: login
            form_login_ldap:
                service: app.ldap
                dn_string: CN={username},OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

Comment: Symfony 2.8+ now contains an LDAP Component, see [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component)

Comment: Hey @LMS94 can you please check the above edits

Comment: This is basically saying that you haven't defined the server "app.ldap" in your services.yml file

Comment: Hey thx for answer well I do i used the code like on the documentation. posted this service in app/config/services.yml, check the edit if u have time please.

Comment: Do you still get the same error?